# run process in background using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, workmanagertaskexecutor

How can I run some process in background using Spring Boot? This is an example of what I need:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMySqlApplication {

    @Autowired
    AppUsersRepo appRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMySqlApplication.class, args);

        while (true) {
            Date date = new Date();
            System.out.println(date.toString());
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just use the @Scheduled-Annotation.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void reportCurrentTime() {
     log.info("The time is now " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
}
```

https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/:

> The Scheduled annotation defines when a particular method runs. NOTE: This example uses fixedRate, which specifies the interval between method invocations measured from the start time of each invocation.

Comment: Thank u i want to chage the fixedRate to infinity

Comment: Why would you do this? In your example you could just set the rate to 3000, so you dont't need to do the TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3); anymore, as your method get's executed every 3000 ms.

Answer (score 12):

You can use Async behaviour. When you call the method and the current thread does wait for it to be finished.

Create a configurable class like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }
}
```

And then used in a method:

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void someAsyncMethod(...) {}
```

Have a look at [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) for more info

Comment: Does or Does not?

Comment: And what do these annotations do?

Comment: exactly, if the current thread is blocked until it finish then it is not async